# Can I make online multiplayer games using flash?

Tags: flash, macos, multiplayer

I want to make a simple game so that I can play against my friends at school. The school uses macs. Also if you can't  make online games with flash what can I use. Also can they be 3-d if I eventually get good at making games?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RuneScape](http://www.runescape.com/) uses a Java applet; this is a good option for multiplayer games.

However, [AdventureQuest](http://www.adventurequest.com/) is a Flash game and I think it's semi-multiplayer.

There seem to be some decent results, both examples and tutorials, if you do a Google search for [multiplayer flash game](http://www.google.com/search?q=multiplayer+flash+game).

Comment: would flash be my best bet because i don't know any language besides apple script so i am going to have to teach myself?

Comment: In that case, start off on the right foot. I would not use Flash. One engine that I found fun and easy was Panda3D. It's a real 3D engine. You can write games in Python. Disney uses it. Check it out: http://www.panda3d.org/

AFAIK, network games from the browser are possible. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I'll be able to make online games that run on widows and mac right?

Comment: Features: "Convenient installer packages for Windows, Mac OSX and Linux" - but I don't see anything about a browser plugin, and Python doesn't natively work in-browser. Java is cross-platform but probably too over your head at this point. Spend a little time looking at these engines such as Panda3D, but if you can't find anything you fall in love with, go with Flash. I think you'll have the most success, and I'm sure you can figure out a way to make multiplayer games with it.

Comment: @Ricket, I've actually used this, not just read their website. Here is a discussion about the plugin. http://www.panda3d.org/phpbb2/viewtopic.php?t=7484

@mtwisterr, you might want to have a look at devmaster.net for other engines. There is a really nice java 3D engine that has a browser as well. I think it's called jmonkey. I played around with that as well. You may have more luck with the browser plugin as it was mature a long time ago.
Tip: 3D engine might not be a complete Game Engine. Check for physics, animation, etc.

Comment: @mtwisterr, If you've never written a game before, start with a single player game - 2D or even text based, but not 3D. Next try single player 3D. Then multiplayer 3D. Or course if 2D is what you want to do, then forget any 3D engine. Again, I've found a lot of good resources on devmaster.net.

Comment: Also note that Flash is almost certainly what you should use if you want the end result to run in a browser. If you want a native application, dedicated game engines will be a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the book [ActionScript for Multiplayer Games and Virtual Worlds](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321643364).  I've only leafed through it, but it looks at the basics of setting up multiplayer games (and servers) using ActionScript (which is the language of Flash).  You can set up a development environment and server for free (although one reviewer complains that the development environment doesn't work on the mac).

Answer (score 1):

there are several good multiplayer game toolkits for flash. here are a couple to look into:

union
http://www.unionplatform.com/

electroserver
http://www.electrotank.com/

colin

Answer (score 0):

"Also if you can't make online games with flash what can I use? Also can they be 3-d?"

Well, you can certainly make games with Flash, and there are libraries such as [Papervision3D](http://www.papervision3d.org/) that can help with the 3D part.

However, there is another engine that's been growing in popularity - [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/unity/) - that you should seriously consider. It's the same basic concept as Flash, a Browser plugin (although Unity can also make stand-alone executables), but is a *lot* more powerful, especially for 3D animation.